# Cannot serve firebase cloud function locally

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting an error in express-serve-static core when trying to build my firebase cloud function locally.
How do I fix this?

I've tried reinstalling the node packages but without luck.

```
node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts:31:10 - error TS2305: Module '"../qs"' has no exported member 'ParsedQs'.

31 import { ParsedQs } from "qs";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by installing `@types/qs`.

```
npm i @types/qs@6.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to return to `@types/express-serve-static-core@4.17.5` (instead of the latest `4.17.7`).
If you don't have this package in you dependencies, install it explicitly.

```
npm install -D @types/express-serve-static-core@4.17.5
```

I had the same problem and returning to the version `4.17.5` worked for me.

Comment: Seems like there are some updates that are intended for the main express types version that isn't published yet...